# Keras: keeps the same prediction for different inputs

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I am learning how to use keras and I keep getting some problems. I will try to be as much specific as possible.

My task: I am trying to create a neural network to predict opening status for a domestic residence.

I have a dataset with 524729 examples. I use 70% as training set and 30% as test set. I am reaching 70+% of acc in my tests but for some reason every time that I try to predict an output I get the same values.

Right now, I have the following topology:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(15, input_shape=(13, ), kernel_initializer='random_normal'))
model.add(Dense(15, activation='softplus'))
model.add(Dense(15, activation='softplus'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()

sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.3, nesterov=True)


model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mae', 'acc'])

model.fit(X_training, Y_training, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), epochs=1, batch_size=32)
```

and I use:

```
model.predict(np_inputRN, verbose=0)
```

to predict the output but for some reason I keep getting the same values.

```
0.0172018650919,0.498908281326,0.984391093254,0.485811322927,0.480756670237,0.984736263752,0.536143004894,0.475958675146,0.494080305099,0.488458126783
```

Can some one help me?

==========================================================================
@Aiven :

```
Data Set: 524729
Test Set[30%]: 157418
Training Set [70%]: 367310
X_training.shape: (367311, 13)
Y_training.shape: (367311, 10)
X_test.shape: (157419, 13)
Y_test.shape: (157419, 10)

np_inputRN.shape: (1, 13)
```

Comment: what are shapes of your `x_training`, `y_training` and `np_inputRN`? what dataset are you using (is it some public one)? How can you explain using `kernel_initializer='random_normal'` for first layer? also use can use `input_shape=13` and `optimizer='adam'`. Are you sure that you make predictions on different data?

Comment: Training for just one epoch is not going to get you very far.

Comment: If you are performing a classification - I'd advice also to change the loss to `binary_crossentropy`

Comment: @Aiven , the dataset is not public. It is a selection from simulations that I've done using Energy Plus using random values for the openings status. Also, for the first layer I've used it because I found it on a book, and I was experimenting it. And I have added the information that you ask in the "Ask" section above.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I am experimenting different scenarios, do you suggest any particular value for it?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko I am not performing a classification because my problem is not divided in classes, would it be helpful in my case?

Comment: so it's regression task and you are trying to output embeddings?

Comment: Yes, that's the task. Do you have any idea on how to improve my NN?

Comment: did you find a solution ?